# adding item in the dictionary coming from a list resulted in TypeError

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, typeerror

this is the code:

```
import bisect

data = {'sal': 25000} # stored data from user input
table = {1249.99: 36.30, 1749.99: 54.50, 2249.99: 72.70, 2749.99: 90.80, 
         3249.99: 109.00, 3749.99: 127.20, 4249.99: 145.30, 4749.99: 163.50, 
         5249.99: 181.70, 5749.99: 199.80, 6249.99: 218.00, 6749.99: 236.20,
         7249.99: 254.30, 7749.99: 272.50, 8249.99: 290.70, 8749.99: 308.80, 
         9249.99: 327.00, 9749.99: 345.20, 10249.99: 363.30, 10749.99: 381.50, 
         11249.99: 399.70, 11749.99: 417.80, 12249.99: 436.00, 12749.99: 
         454.20, 13249.99: 472.30, 13749.99: 490.50, 14249.99: 508.70, 
         14749.99: 526.80, 15249.99: 545.00, 15749.99: 563.20, 15750.00: 
         581.30}

# get corresponding value from the table
table_bisect = bisect.bisect(sorted(table), data['sal'])
if table_bisect >= 30:
   table_bisect = 30
else:
  table_bisect = table_bisect
s_table = sorted(table.value())
data['new'] = ''.join(s_table[table_bisect:(table_bisect+1)] 
# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, float found
```

Everything works fine, until the last line, which return the error above. How can I fix the error or what are the work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because if you slice with `list[index:index+1]`, it simply returns one value, which in this case is a float:

```
>>> y = [21, 4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 7, 9]
>>> y[5:6]
[3]
>>> ''.join(y[5:6])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
>>>
```

Instead, just do the following:

```
data['new'] = s_table[table_bisect:(table_bisect+1)][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to do this:

```
data['new'] = ''.join(str(s_table[table_bisect:(table_bisect+1)]))
```

the `join()` method expects string type if you need to use it.